# How to prevent memory leak in React when using Firebase authentication

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a simple React authentication web app, and whenever I try to log in, it doesn't work on the first attempt. The log in only works on the second attempt every time.

When I click the first time, I get the following error in the console.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

The authentication part is below:

```
import {auth} from '../../configuration/firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth (){
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {

    const[currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const[loading,setLoading] = useState(true)


    const signup = (email, password) => {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    const login = (email, password) => {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
}
```

Below is my function for login in the Login component:

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
            history.push("/home")
        }
        catch{
            alert('Failed to sign in. Check your credentials')
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `history.push("/home")` will push the `/home` screen and discard the current screen ("unmount" in React terminology).

When the screen is unmounted, `setLoading(false)` will not have any effect – the screen is already gone, there is nothing to be updated. Thus the warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component".

#### Solution

It's pretty easy to fix: just make sure state mutation happens before navigating away (i.e. `setLoading(false)` before `history.push`). For example:

```js
async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
            setLoading(false)
            history.push("/home")
        }
        catch{
            setLoading(false)
            alert('Failed to sign in. Check your credentials')
        }
}
```

Comment: Still it logins in the second attempt only. But there is no warning or error in the console this time

Comment: @Thiluxan Great. The login issue is a separate problem, that has nothing to do with the warning. Why don't you edit your question and show a bit more code on how the authentication is handled?